# Firebase Firestore querySnapshot appears to return bogus cache result when offline

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore `querySnapshot` appears to incorrectly return a cached result, even though no cache is present, when the device is offline. If this is intended behaviour, how can I tell if any particular result is a "made-up" cached result or from a genuine cache?

Specifically the following code:

```
val snapshotListener = firestore.collection("codes").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
    Log.v("firebase", "numDocuments=${value?.documents?.size}, isCached=${value?.metadata?.isFromCache}, error=${error}")
}
```

When run on a brand new install, having removed all storage/cache, and **no internet** returns as follows:

```
(...)  numDocuments=0, isCached=true, error=null
```

I would argue this is incorrect - no such result could have been cached because (a) it's the first time I've ever made the request, and (b) even if this weren't the case, I know for a fact that there *are* documents at that location.

So the question is: if this is intended behaviour, how do I properly inform my users? Rather than drawing my UI with a "no results" banner (which logically follow this result, but would be incorrect), I need to inform them of the comms error.

One possible way is by looking at the result's `metadata.isFromCache` and ignoring the result if it's true. But that would negate the whole purpose of the cache, which is otherwise very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK sets `isFromCache` to `true` when the result is based on its local knowledge, and that knowledge may not be up to date with the status on the database server (i.e. when it's offline or when there's no active listener for the requested data).

I find it best to interpret the `isFromCache` property as "this value may not be up to date with what exists on the database server", and usually represent it in a similar fashion to your users.

Ignoring data that has `isFromCache` set to `true` is also an option of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is it completely safe to ignore all isFromCache=true results? I.e. can I be certain that every time I get a cached result, it's always (eventually) followed by a live, online one?

Comment: "completely safe" is hard to say, which is why I explained what each value of the property means. --- If the client is connected to the server and you're using a realtime listener, then you'll indeed get an updated snapshot with the data from the server - but also have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes